# How to create mysql database in ec2 instance using terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created EC2 and My sql instance using below code and it executed successfully. what is the procedure if we need to create mysql database in a particular ec2 instance, if there are multiple running.I could see db-instance in aws console . Even though there is option available in console to create database, I need to perform through terraform code.

```
resource "aws_instance" "DB-Server"
 {
  ami = "ami-051f75c6"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name="Key-pair
}
resource "aws_db_instance" "default"
 {
   allocated_storage    = 20
   storage_type         = "gp2"
   engine               = "mysql"
   engine_version       = "5.7"
   instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
   name                 = "mydb"
   username             = "username"
   password             = "XXXX"
   `enter code here`parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you wanting to specify which EC2 instance to create your MySQL instance on? If so, that really isn't how AWS RDS works. Do you want to do your own MySQL install on an EC2 instance and not use RDS?

Comment: Hi, yes, i want to install own mysql in EC2 instance.

Comment: that's not the role of terraform, think about ansible, chef to automation these installation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you would like to install MySQL on your own EC2 instance using Terraform, I would suggest you use the [user_data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) functionality of EC2. User data allows you to define a script to perform installation or configuration of an EC2 instance when it is deployed. Terraform offers hooks into that like so.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                yum install -y mysql56-server
              EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Above is a really simple approach to performing the task. You just need to customize the user_data section to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Terraform `local-exec` or `remote-exec` provisioner. It allows you to do anything you could do with bash. When your Terraform code is done bringing up the EC2 instance, you invoke the local/remote exec which runs a script to install MySQL.